# How to offset a bind date variable that is formatted

Tags: angularjs, filter, datetimeoffset

In my calendar I show the year:

`<div class="calLabel">{{daySelected | date:"yyyy"}}</div>`

and I want a button that let's you select the next year, but I can't see to print the value of the next year. I'm looking for something like this:

`<button class="btn calBtn rightBtn">{{daySelected | date:"yyyy" + 1 }}</button>`

*Note - I'd rather not have another `$scope` variable just for that.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button class="btn calBtn rightBtn">{{(daySelected | date:"yyyy") - 0 + 1}}</button>
```

This is just a hack. Ideally you need to add a filter like toNumber and then add 1 to it.

```
<button class="btn calBtn rightBtn">{{daySelected | date:"yyyy"|toNumber + 1}}</button>
```

toNumber will have parseInt(value)

Cheers